# Trouble creating assert function

Tags: c++

This is my assert function (it wont compile "error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers"):

```
#define CHAR(x) #x

template<typename T>
inline void ASSERT(T x)
{
    if(!x)
    {
        std::string s("ERROR! Assert " + CHAR(x) + " failed. In file " + __FILE__ +
                      " at line " + __LINE__ + ".");
            std::wstring temp(s.length(), L' ');
            std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), temp.begin());
            getLogger().Write(temp);
        }
    }
```

Any idea of how to fix it?

Comment: Note that you can't write this as a function; the use of `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` require that it is implemented as a macro (assuming you want the file and line in which the `ASSERT` is used).

Comment: @James McNelles even if I make the function inline?

Comment: Yes, even then. Inlining doesn't affect the output of a function. (If it does, your compiler is broken.)

Comment: @Tiago Costa: It needs to be a macro because `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are preprocessor macros which will be "magically" replaced by constants later.

Comment: When you're writing C++, you should use `std::string`. Then this entire issue just disintegrates. (This means that each [sort of] string literal in your code should be wrapped in a temporary instantiation of `std::string`; then you can rely on `std::string`'s `op+` to do the heavy lifting for you.) In this case, as others have said, you can just rely on preprocessor concatenation, but this won't always be available to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String Literals are easily reduced to `char` pointers, which cannot be added as you try to do with `"ERROR! Assert " + CHAR(x) + " failed. In file "...`.  However, C++ has the handy feature of doing this *automatically* before compilation! (the preprocessor does this).  Even better, it has a handy tool for making wide strings at compile time. So, you want:

```
#define _T(x) L ## x
#define CHAR(x) #x
#define CHAR2(x) CHAR(x)
#define ASSERT(x) ASSERT2(x, CHAR(x), __FILE__, CHAR2(__LINE__))
#define ASSERT2(x, t, f, l) \
if(!x) \
    getLogger().Write(L"ERROR! Assert " _T(t) L" failed. In file " _T(f) L" at line " _T(l) L".");
```

http://ideone.com/0ibcj

Comment: No compile errors. But #define CHAR(x) #x is not working correctly... Its outputting: "ERROR! Assert x failed. In file __FILE__ at line __LINE__."

Comment: Are __FILE__ and __LINE__ displaying properly?  Hard to tell from your comment.  Also, did you make ASSERT into a macro or a function?

Comment: No they are not displayed properly... I turned ASSERT into a macro

Comment: What happens if you remove the CHAR() macro and put in just # then?

Comment: I've changed the code to this: http://ideone.com/gBceP. But I get 3 compile errors: error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments / error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'string' / error C2059: syntax error : ')'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3508/discussion-between-tiago-costa-and-mooing-duck)

Answer (score 0):

`"ERROR! Assert "` is a null-terminated, C-style string. You can't execute `operator+` on it.

Comment: Sure you can. It just doesn't do what's desired here, and there are restrictions on what the other operand can be.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error is quite clear; you are trying to apply the + operator to string literals. A quick way to fix it is enclosing the first string literal in `std::string()`.

As @James McNellis pointed out, note that **FILE** and **LINE** will point to the file and line of the assert function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the + operator to concatenate two `char*`s; you need `printf` or some sort of thing for that.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

1. Generally an assert should break into the debugger or dump if one is not attached. This will not.
2. As already mentioned, your **LINE** and **FILE** require use in a macro
3. You need a couple "helper" macros to get the strings working properly

Try something along these lines:

```
#define ASSERT_QUOTE_(x) #x
#define ASSERT_QUOTE_(x) ASSERT_QUOTE_(x)

#define MY_ASSERT(cond) \
  if(cond) {} else { \
    std::stringstream ss; \
    ss << "ERROR! Assert " << ASSERT_QUOTE(cond) << " failed. In file " << __FILE__ << " at line " << __LINE__ << "."; \
    getLogger().Write(ss.str()); \
  }
```

Be careful trying to use STL here however. I suggest you have your logger's Write() function take variable arguments and process them with printf() or perhaps [boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/format/doc/format.html)